# Latex gives output of pictures, tables which are all mixed together. How can I solve it?

Tags: tables

I have written the following code, which has a lot of tables pictures and plots in it. All of these appear unorganized and distorted in the ouput. Can anyone help me solve it?
In the beginning I have written a code for tally symbols (which is correct).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcount\tmpnum
\def\tallymarks#1{\leavevmode \lower1bp\vbox to9bp{}%
   \tmpnum=#1
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum<5 \kern1bp \tallynum\tmpnum \else \tallyV \fi
         \advance\tmpnum by-5
         \ifnum\tmpnum>0 \repeat
}
\def\tallynum#1{\bgroup\tmpnum=#1\relax
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum>0
         \kern1bp \tallyI \kern1bp
         \advance\tmpnum by-1
         \repeat
   \egroup
}
\def\tallyI{\pdfliteral{q .5 w 0 -1 m 0 8 l S Q}}
\def\tallyV{\kern1bp\pdfliteral{q .5 w -1 0 m 9 7 l S Q}\tallynum4\kern1bp }

\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen}
}

\begin{document}

In datasets, we often find variables taking a wide range of values whether these are categorical or quantitive in nature. To make sense of the data we want to organize them in a way such that we can catch a glimpse of how the data is distributed within the dataset and if there exists a pattern in the distribution of the values. These can be undertaken as follows. We can count the number of occurrences of each value for a variable and then demonstrate it through a frequency table or we can make use of bins and each observation that falls within the range of a specific bin is then added up and afterward displayed in a frequency table. I elaborate on these with two examples.
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \newline \textbf{Example 1}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \newline
     Suppose we have a categorical variable in which the blood type of participants in a survey is compiled. The observed values are shown in the table below. We are interested in the frequency of each blood type in this data, that is we want to count the number of occurrences of each blood type.
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \newline
    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|lllll|}
    \hline
    O  & A & A  & O & O  \\
    B  & B & A  & A & A  \\
    A  & O & O  & O & B  \\
    O  & O & A  & O & A  \\
    A  & O & AB & B & O  \\
    AB & B & O  & A & AB \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    We summarize the data in a frequency table by first inserting a column with the labels of the observed data, then tally the numbers of each blood group---concluding with the frequency of each blood group. This procedure is based on the approach that the frequencies are counted by hand---this can of course get complicated when the data set concerns a large sample size in which case we can use the \texttt{count()} function in R. The frequency table can also be visualized in a barplot, like below with the following R code.
    \begin{lstlisting}
    bloodgroup <- c("O",    "A",    "A",    "O",    "O",
                    "B",    "B",    "A",    "A",    "A",
                    "A",    "O",    "O",    "O",    "B",
                    "O",    "O",    "A",    "O",    "A",
                    "A",    "O",    "AB",   "B",    "O",
                    "AB",   "B",    "O",    "A",    "AB")
    
    xx <- barplot(table(bloodgroup),ylim=c(0, 14))
    coords <- as.numeric(table(bloodgroup))
    text(x = xx, y = coords, label = coords, 
         cex = 0.8,pos = 3, col = "red")
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
    \textbf{Blood Group} & \textbf{Tally} & \textbf{Frequency}   \\\midrule
    A    & \tallymarks{10}  & 10    \\ 
    B  & \tallymarks{5} & 5 \\ 
    AB  & \tallymarks{3} & 3 \\ 
    O  & \tallymarks{12} & 12 \\\bottomrule
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{example-image}
    \end{center}
    
    \textbf{Example 2}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \newline In this example, we use a continuous variable BMI that stores the body mass index of  30 participants. We are aiming to determine how much of these participants fall in the category of underweight, healthy weight, overweight, and obese. The range of all these bins are construed as follows: below 18.5 is underweight, between 18.5 to 25 healthy weight, from 25 to 30 overweight and over 30 obese. The observed data is given below.
    
    \begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|llllll|}
    \hline
    18.2 & 31.2 & 24.3 & 21.5 & 23.8 & 31.8 \\
    22.1 & 15.2   & 27.8 & 17.8 & 19.2 & 23.3 \\
    26.1 & 17.3 & 18.6 & 19.4 & 16.2 & 19.6 \\
    16.8 & 19.7 & 17.3 & 20.8 & 24.4 & 28.4 \\
    23.8 & 20.1 & 25.9 & 33.2 & 26.7 & 24.7 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    To create a frequency table for this data, we follow the steps as laid for the previous example---except that we use bins with a range as labeled above. For example for the observation 22.1 we lookup in the given ranges to find in which bin this value belongs; which is the second bin.
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
    \textbf{BMI Range} & \textbf{Tally} & \textbf{Frequency}   \\\midrule
     Underweight: <18.5 is   & \tallymarks{10}  & 10    \\ 
    Healthyweight: 18.5---25  & \tallymarks{5} & 5 \\ 
    Overweight: 25---30  & \tallymarks{3} & 3 \\ 
    Obese: >30  & \tallymarks{12} & 12 \\\bottomrule
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    The barplot for this data is achieved in R, with the following code.
    \begin{lstlisting}
    bloodgroup <- c("O",    "A",    "A",    "O",    "O",
                    "B",    "B",    "A",    "A",    "A",
                    "A",    "O",    "O",    "O",    "B",
                    "O",    "O",    "A",    "O",    "A",
                    "A",    "O",    "AB",   "B",    "O",
                    "AB",   "B",    "O",    "A",    "AB")
    barplot(prop.table(table(bloodgroup)))  
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please provide a test code that people can run. The fragment that you post looks Very weird, why are you needing to inject raw pdf code in a document, or use tex primitives such as `\def`, similarly the combinations of `\newline` and `\vspace` seem very strange? But as the code is not posted in a form that can be run it is hard to guess the intent/

Comment: please try to make a complete document that shows the problem, you can replace `Rplot` by `example-image` if that still shows the problem, it is available for testing

Comment: I added the missing packages and `\end{center}` so that your code could be used, but it isn't clear what is wrong with the output. Can you say what output you expected.  Note that the empty option `\begin{table}[]` specifies that the table may not be placed anywhere. LaTeX ignores this and warns `LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.` but it is better to delete the `[]`

Comment: I have edited the codes. I also inject R codes in it by \lstset.

Comment: if you mean the table and the image coming side by side, place a blank line before `\includegraphics` you are forcing it to the same line as the table, which looks odd.

Comment: The text does not appear in a proper order.

Comment: It appears in the order that you specified it, you may want it in a different order but if you do not say what that is, we can not know. Note the only function of the `table` and `figure` environments are to make their content a float, it take them out of the main document flow and allow them to be inserted elsewhere to help with page breaking. do not use `table` if you do not want that (but expect bad white space at page breaks.

Comment: Note you should also remove all the `\vspace{\baselineskip}` and `\newline`

Comment: What you **can** do if pack a bunch of tabulars and graphics with captions into one big table or picture.  See \captionof from the caption or capt-of packages.  You can also use the paracol package to display floats in columns.

Comment: I have added example pictures for what the actual text should look like.

Comment: Do your images and tables get a caption and a number and will you refer back to them in the text? If not an if you absolutely do want your images and tables to appear exactly where they were inserted in the code, you could replace the `table` environments with `center` environments. If you use this approach, please be aware: If a table is too large to fit into the remaining space on the bottom of a page, the table is moved to the following page leaving the space on the previous page empty.

Comment: They do not get a caption.